# My CNN's validation accuracy never exceed 75 percent

Tags: python, keras

I am a newbie for CNN, I followed [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) and build my own model from scratch.

When I run my model, the validation accuracy fluctuate but not increase. I have 10 classes with me. I tried to play around with the learning rate, but not much different. It seems like the model always overfitting. My validation accuracy normally fluctuate around 0.70 to 0.73,while training keeps increasing.

For my model, I tried to follow NiN model, but I am not sure whether this is the right code since not much reference for me to refer.

I am using this data generator, I couldn't do k-fold cross validation. Is there any suggestion I can used to increase my validation and testing accuracy?

Thank you very much.

```
nb_train_samples = 8804
nb_validation_samples = 2512
nb_test_samples = 1263

train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/Z/Documents/Python Scripts/10 species dataset TVT/Training Dataset'
validation_data_dir = 'C:/Users/Z/Documents/Python Scripts/10 species dataset TVT/Validation Dataset'
test_data_dir = 'C:/Users/Z/Documents/Python Scripts/10 species dataset TVT/Testing Dataset'

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(192, (5, 5), input_shape=input_shape,strides=4))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(160, (1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(96, (1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(192, (5, 5)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(192, (1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(192, (1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(192, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(192, (1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(10, (1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format=None))

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

learning_rate = 0.00001
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs
adam = Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay_rate)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size=(img_width, img_height),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_data_dir,
target_size=(img_width, img_height),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
test_data_dir,
target_size=(img_width, img_height),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

history = model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

test_steps_per_epoch = np.math.ceil(test_generator.samples / test_generator.batch_size)
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes=test_generator.classes
class_labels = list(test_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = metrics.classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
```

Comment: what's the classes distribution in test data and train data??

Comment: 7:2:1 for each class. @Inder

Comment: take a look at the predictions of the model, most likely its predicting a single class

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: You must have saved your model , just load that model and do a model.predict(x) 
x will be your testx

Comment: I missed my predict_generator just now, I edited the code inside. Besides this, do you have any suggestions I can do to increase my validation accuracy? Thank you so much for reply me.

Comment: shuffle the data, use a bigger batch size, with repetitive insertion of the minority classes, so it doesn't overfit on a single class

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion.